# How to declare Labels in xaml for use in both WPF and Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, label

I am working on a [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in a Silverlight project in visual studio 2010.

This user control uses Labels as follows:

```
<sdk:Label .../>
-or-
<sdk:Label>
  singleObject
</sdk:Label>
-or-
<sdk:Label>stringContent</sdk:Label>
```

as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

However, when I create a WPF project link it to Silverlight Library Project:

(by adding existing items (Add Link) to cs classes and the .xaml file defining the control)

I get the following error in build:

**The tag 'Label' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk'. Line 49 Position 18. myfile.xaml 49  18  MyLibraryWPF**

This [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label.aspx) shows that labels in WPF are declared without the `sdk:`

like this:

```
<Label>
  Content
</Label>
```

yet, I cannot change that in my Silverlight project. It will be a real waste to create a whole new project and duplicate the code to make it work.

How to make the Labels work with both Silverlight and WPF projects?

Comment: If you want to reuse xaml, you need to target the "lowest common" aka Silverlight. Do not include toolkit controls. For a label you can use a TextBlock

Comment: but TextBlocks do not have background colors

Comment: @Saher: They do have Background color.   
<TextBlock Background="Red"></TextBlock>

Comment: @Nitesh No Background does not exist for TextBlock

Comment: at least I get error when I try to set the property

Comment: Yes it is not available in SilverLight but in WPF. Strange !!

Comment: you're right that's what it is. Weird man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a piece of Code in xaml that can be shared by WPF and Silverlight and looks like label with Background coloe:

```
<Border Margin="3,0,3,3" Background="#FF00B050">
                <TextBlock Text="txt122" FontSize="13" FontWeight="SemiBold" Height="21" Name="label15" Width="133"  ></TextBlock>
            </Border>
```

This means that a Label cannot be used in a shared XAML.